# Jquery form bind and rebind issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with Preview and Publishbuttons.

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="preview();" >Preview</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="submitform();">Publish</a>

  function preview()
  {
    $("#MyForm").attr('target', '_blank').unbind('submit').submit();
    console.log($("#MyForm").data('events'));
  }

  function submitform()
  {
    $('#MyForm').attr('target', '_self').bind('submit').submit();
    console.log($("#MyForm").data('events'));
  }
```

When I preview form (submits in newpage) and again publish, form is not binded with submit event. Is anything wrong in binding the form?

Comment: Note that there is a typo in the 2nd "fucntion"

Comment: Hi, Mistake happen while posting question. Thanks

Comment: $('#MyForm').attr('target', '_blank').bind('submit').submit(); did u try this ? unless if you want to load the form in the same page without posting back you should use ajax

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
function submitHandler() {
  //body
}

function preview() {
  $("#MyForm").attr('target', '_blank').unbind('submit', submitHandler);
  console.log($("#MyForm").data('events'));
}


function submitform() {
  $('#MyForm').attr('target', '_self').bind('submit', submitHandler);
  console.log($("#MyForm").data('events'));
 }
```

In your implementation you don't attach any event handlers to the form.

Comment: Hi Preview and publish is the a tag <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="preview();" >Preview</a> and <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="submitform();">Publish</a>. submithandler doesn't works..

Comment: Man, `submitHandler` should be invoked when the form is submitted. When you expect it to be invoked?

Comment: Hi Actually I want to skip the jquery validation on preview and enable the validation on publish.

Comment: I guess you should read some of the documentation of jQuery before continuing the discussion here. Start with https://api.jquery.com/bind/